# Manipulating streams in child process

Tags: c, process, stream, fork

I'm having a problem understanding how these concepts work and if you can help me please keep in mind that I don't have much experience in C or OS related stuff.

I realize that when I create a child process text, data and stack are copied and that child has access to previously opened file descriptors. I tried running something like this from main function

```
...
pid = fork();
if(pid > 0) {
    pid = wait(&child_status);
    fprintf(fp, "smth");
} 
else if (pid == 0) {
    fclose(fp);
}
```

And it turns out it actually does print "smth" to file associated with fp stream.

Q: Does this mean that connection between the program and file is duplicated when I create child process and closing it in child doesn't affect the parent or it is not possible to close connection inside child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `fork`ing, each process will have its own copy of the file, so closing the file in one process, does not mean that the file will be closed in the other process.

And about your code, you have closed the file in the child (not the parent) process only. So, in order to save your changes you have to close it too in the parent process. Also, don't forget to handle `fork` error cases:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid > 0) {
    pid = wait();
    fprintf(fp, "smth");
    fclose(fp);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    fclose(fp);
} else {
    perror("Fork error");
    return 1;
}
```

If you want the `fprintf` to be executed from the child process, you have to change your `if` conditions as following:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
    /* Child */
    pid = wait();
    fprintf(fp, "smth");
    fclose(fp);
} else if (pid > 0) {
    /* Parent */
    fclose(fp);
} else {
    perror("Fork error");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question with the first part of your answer. As for executing fprintf from child, I think I already knew how fork returns but your example made me wonder what wait() does when called from inside child process? I guess nothing? edit: bad english

Comment: @bo2032, `wait(2)` waits for state changes in children. So calling this function from the child, which doesn't have children, "do nothing".

Comment: Each process has an entry in file descriptor table poining to the open file. Not a copy of the file itself.

Comment: @TonyTannous, yes that's true, but what I mean here by copy, is that each process has its own `FILE *`.